# React hooks- How to pass function between component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm completely new to React so I'm not sure if I have the right title.

I have two component, Header and Product. I want to render the content of Product component when a button is clicked in Header, but I'm not sure how to "pass" this function from Header to Product. Would anyone like to help?  Here's my code.

In Header

```
import React from "react";
import handlePage from "./ProductList";
//I'm trying to import the function, there was no error so I'm not sure if it's success or not.

const Header = () => {
  return (
    {/* some content is skipped */}
<Nav onClick={()=>handlePage('women');})> Women </Nav>
    {/* more content is skipped */}
}
```

In Product

```
const Product= ()=>{
  const [product, setProduct] = useState();
  const handlePage = () => {

    return setProduct();
    // Expect to return empty content once clicked
  };

  return(

    {/* some content is skipped */}
   )
}

Thanks everyone for help!
```

Comment: Where do you use the `<Product/>` component?  Did you mean to add it to the `<Header/>` component?  When you do, you can conditionally render it or not render it based on any kind of state that you're tracking in `Header`.  But given the code shown it's not really clear what you mean, currently these two components are unrelated.

Comment: take a look at `lift up the state` concept in React. your approach makes it hard

Comment: Assuming your `Product` is in a file called `ProjectList`, then the line `import handlePage from "./ProductList";` isn't doing what you think it's doing. It would depend what you are exporting from that file.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to pass data and functions between components is using the props field which looks something like

```
<Header prop1={} prop2={} />
const Header = (props) => {
    //props.prop1 and props.prop2 can now be used in this scope
}
```

A good practice is to pass handler functions from parent to child node. This way if a sibling node also has to utilize the same handler, it can be passed down as props.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

Header component

```
import Product from "../Product";
import { useState } from "react";
//import handlePage from "./ProductList";

const Header = () => {
    const [prodType, setProdType] = useState('')
  return (
    <div>
    <label onClick={() => setProdType('Women')}>Women</label>
    <Produto prodType={prodType} />  
    </div>
    )
}

export default Header
```

Product component

```
const Product = (props) => {
    return(
    <div>{props.prodType}</div>
    )
}

export default Product
```